# Apple Mac Pro as part of a MaaS Cluster?

Tags: server, juju, maas, macosx, apple

Has anyone tried putting a Apple Mac Pro in a MaaS cluster.

Basically we have a internal cluster for development builds, continuous integration, automated testing etc.  We need to support Linux, Windows, and Mac.  So far that's meant, having one process for everything, but the Macs. However this setup isn't sustainable.  It causes us to only test on the latest MacOSX, where for other OS's, we test/support two versions back.

Anyway hence, the idea of managing the apple machines using MaaS and Juju.  Looks like MaaS has support for controlling the machines through Wakeup on lan (WOL), but I don't see a way of getting Apple hardware to PXE boot.

Has anyone given this a try?  Anyway to control a Apple Mac Pro through IPMI?  Maybe with some sort of external hardware?

To be clear, we are talking about running Ubuntu on the Apple hardware as the host operating system in the MAAS cluster.  The kvm virtual machines would be running MacOSX as the guest.  This lets us use OpenStack, or Juju to manage the virtual machines, and plays nice with the Apple MacOSX licensing restriction that requires running on actual Apple hardware.